# Question concerning two circles that don't intersect and circles that touch them

Tags: geometry, circles

Given two circles that don't intersect, $k_i$ with centers in $O_i$ and radii $r_i$, $i=1,2$, prove that the centers of all circles that touch them lie on one line. Note: this is the case where one of the circles is not inside the other.

I have no clue where to start.

What I tried: centers of any two circles that touch the given circles define a line, call it $p$. Then, given any other circle that touches $k_1$ and $k_2$, I tried to prove that its center lies on $p$, but to no avail.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The centres of all circles touching the given circles from outside have distances $r+r_i$ from $O_i$ with varying $r$. This does not define a straight line unless $r-1=r_2$.

Comment: Right, @HagenvonEitzen. Surely we’re describing a hyperbola here?

Comment: One branch of a hyperbola, and I think it becomes a parabola when the two circles are tangent to one another... Not completely sure, since I never really liked Apollonius diagrams.

Comment: You get a line only if $r_1=r_2$. Otherwise the locus is a branch of hyperbola.

Comment: @N.Bach you get a hyperbola even if the circles touch or overlap, you can see this by considering 'circles that touch them' which are much larger than the original two, for which the centers all lie on lines.

Comment: @Eddy Took me a while to get what you were saying, but makes sense. I'll probably remember it from now on. On a side note, I looked into why I remembered about some cases that yield a parabola... In general the locus of points equidistant from two circles is a subset of some conic, and looking only at the discriminant, that conic can sometimes be a "parabola"... except that in those cases, it always degenerates into a single line. And one of these cases is when a circle contains the other, and they are tangent.